# Upload images to Wordpress, include in slideshow

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to upload images to a post or to a custom post type(s). Every image should then be wrapped with a li tag as shown below, in order to create a slideshow with the images. The whole post should be wrapped inside a div and a ul, also shown below.

To get an idea of how it looks look [here](http://felipes.se/hh). Right now I use posts and every post is coded manualy. There are four different slideshows but they have the same images. You will find navigation-arrows next to every picture.

```
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="slide1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="slide2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="slide3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="slide4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible? What method should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: http://johnford.is/programmatically-pull-attachments-from-wordpress-posts/

Essentially what you will need to do is to go through the attachments of each post then spit out the list. I'm not sure how you want to implement this though, you could put it in the post template or perhaps make a shortcode to use it.